# How to add several rows for each item for a ListBox in winform

Tags: winforms, listbox

I have a collection with 50 objects.

Each object contains several things but we have at least

```
OrgNr, Register_Id, Name, MailDate, Subject
```

for each object.

Assume these have the following values

- OrgNr = "2556745-8145"
- Register_Id = "1001"
- Name = "Thailaan Asian Market"
- MailDate = "2016-05-23 13:01:20"
- Subject = "LPP failure"

So when I read the first object and want to add the above five fields to the ListBox I want it to be displayed like this and as one column.

```
2556745-8145/1001
Thailaan Asian Market
2016-05-23 13:01:20
LPP failure
```

So all these five fields is like one item and should be clickable.

I have been looing everywhere but the only example I have found is this
http://www.codeproject.com/articles/2695/an-editable-multi-line-listbox-for-net.

I can't use this example because I want to be able to control when I want to add CR LF which is after each written field value

//Tony

Comment: Define "should be clickable".  Do you mean selectable text, as in the example from CodeProject?  Or do you mean like a web link or button that has some direct action associated with it?

Comment: It might be somewhat academic...  Either way, I might suggest a `UserControl` for the individual list items, perhaps coupled with a container control such as `FlowLayoutPanel` to list them.

Comment: The post containing the five fields should be clickable to call a event handler similar to a button or link. So you mean I can't use a ListBox but should instead use a UserControl to add to a FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: I suppose if you just want the click and nothing more, either would work.  You just need a reliable way to identify which item got the click and then react.

Comment: I don't think I can use a user control because of this. Is it possible to have a event handler for the whole user control similar to when I click a button and not to the individual controls within the user control.

Comment: Just depends on how much interactivity you want.  Most importantly, however, is whether these 5 items are just a formatted blob of text or if they should be independently interactive.  If it's the latter, you should use a `UserControl`.  Otherwise, you could go either way.  And no, the events should be based on the controls the UC owns, and not on the UC itself.